# Rotating body's background image

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, image-rotation

I was wondering how could I rotate my background image and flipping it horizontally without it rotating and flipping the whole web page. I found stuff to rotate background-image for container and such, but none for the whole body of a web page.
Here's what I have, but I don't think it can be of any help:

```
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;

  }

  body::before {
      background-image: url("images/cab06e1517827eff989457c69aae7ea5.png");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: right;
      background-size: 600px;
      z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: -100%;
      left: -100%;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: nope, didn't work.

Comment: It's not any different for the `<body>`. You can have a `body::before` selector just fine.

Comment: I have tried both (I just edited the post) but none did anything. The body:before literally erased my background for some reason

Comment: You need to put `content: ''` there to make it do anything :)

Comment: just did that right now and my background is still empty. :/

Comment: Are you sure about `-100%`? It should be 0, right?

Comment: Tried both and both showed the void.

Comment: Maybe the image URL is wrong?

Comment: I don't think so since the image showed (non-rotated of course) before I did anything to it

Comment: I checked your code and the image appears just fine if I use `content: ''` and change `top` and `left` to `0`.

Comment: this means my issue is somewhere else... I guess I have to check the whole code on my own now then. Thanks for checking

Comment: Play with dev tools, find your `::before` element there and see how it behaves when you change its properties.

Comment: Just did. I've just used a whole new code and it still doesn't work. And for some reason I've noticed the background was the colour I wanted it to be before I even set any background-color. this is messed up...

Comment: Can you put it online?

Comment: I don't mind to show the whole code. Though I have no FTP on this PC, so would it be easier to take this to stack overflow chat so I can send you the whole page's code?

Comment: Sure, put it in the question, preferably as a snippet.

Comment: Alright, here it is. As you can see, it's still pretty empty as I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: You forgot `width` and `height`.

Comment: omg I'm so sorry for taking so much of your time for such a dumb mistake on my end. Thank you, you literally saved my website with width and height.

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed the missing dimensions with Web Tools, as it showed me `0 x 0` when I hovered my mouse over the `::after` element. Dev Tools for the win!

Comment: when i'd hover my mouse over the CSS dev tools showed nothing, that's why I didn't notice I suppose. Thanks again...